# C#: Returning no output parameter after calling ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, .net-3.5, executenonquery

From C# I do below:

```cs
SqlParameter[] Params= new SqlParameter[3];
Params[0] = new SqlParameter("SearchCode", strSearchCode); // strSearchCode is a string
Params[1] = new SqlParameter("@Error", 0);
Params[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
Params[2] = new SqlParameter("@OutputCode", "");
Params[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

int i = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "MySP", Params);

int intError = Convert.ToInt32(Params[1].Value);
string strOutputCode = Convert.ToString(Params[2].Value);
```

`SqlHelper` is a helper class that contains database query methods, I only post here the ones being used in the call:

```cs
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string connectionString, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
{
    if( connectionString == null || connectionString.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "connectionString" );

    // Create & open a SqlConnection, and dispose of it after we are done
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        // Call the overload that takes a connection in place of the connection string
        return ExecuteNonQuery(connection, commandType, commandText, commandParameters);
    }
}

public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
{   
    if( connection == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "connection" );

    // Create a command and prepare it for execution
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    bool mustCloseConnection = false;
    PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, (SqlTransaction)null, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection );

    // Finally, execute the command
    int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    if( mustCloseConnection )
        connection.Close();
    return retval;
}

private static void PrepareCommand(SqlCommand command, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters, out bool mustCloseConnection )
{
    if( command == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "command" );
    if( commandText == null || commandText.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "commandText" );

    // If the provided connection is not open, we will open it
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        mustCloseConnection = true;
        connection.Open();
    }
    else
    {
        mustCloseConnection = false;
    }

    // Associate the connection with the command
    command.Connection = connection;

    int timeOut = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connection.ConnectionString).ConnectTimeout;
    command.CommandTimeout = timeOut; //connection.ConnectionTimeout * 2;

    // Set the command text (stored procedure name or SQL statement)
    command.CommandText = commandText;

    // If we were provided a transaction, assign it
    if (transaction != null)
    {
        if( transaction.Connection == null ) throw new ArgumentException( "The transaction was rollbacked or commited, please provide an open transaction.", "transaction" );
        command.Transaction = transaction;
    }

    // Set the command type
    command.CommandType = commandType;

    // Attach the command parameters if they are provided
    if (commandParameters != null)
    {
        AttachParameters(command, commandParameters);
    }
    return;
}

private static void AttachParameters(SqlCommand command, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
{
    if( command == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "command" );
    if( commandParameters != null )
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter p in commandParameters)
        {
            if( p != null )
            {
                // Check for derived output value with no value assigned
                if ( ( p.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput || 
                    p.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input ) && 
                    (p.Value == null))
                {
                    p.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                command.Parameters.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my stored procedure looks like below:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP] 
    @SearchCode char(10),
    @Error int OUTPUT,
    @OutputCode char(50) OUTPUT         

AS

    DECLARE @Flag1 bit
    DECLARE @IDate date
    DECLARE @FDate date
    DECLARE @TypeM tinyint

    SELECT @OutputCode=SomeField FROM SearchTable WHERE FieldToSearch=@SearchCode
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    begin
        SET @Error=1
        RETURN
    end

    SELECT @Flag1=Flag_1, @TypeM=MyType FROM AnotherTable WHERE Condition1=@OutputCode
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    begin
        SET @Error=2
        RETURN
    end 

    SELECT @IDate=InitDate, @FDate=FinalDate FROM AnotherTable2 WHERE Condition1=@OutputCode
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    begin
        SET @Error=3
        RETURN
    end     

    SELECT SomeField From AnotherTable3 WHERE Condition1=SomeCondition
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    begin
        SET @Error=4
        RETURN
    end 

    SELECT SomeField From AnotherTable4 WHERE Condition1=SomeCondition2
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    begin
        SET @Error=5
        RETURN
    end 

    SET @Error=0
```

The problem I have is that output parameter `@OutputCode` is not being read from C# code when I do:

```cs
string strOutputCode = Convert.ToString(Params[2].Value);
```

`strOutputCode` contains `"0"`.

In case of the another output parameter:

```cs
int intError = Convert.ToInt32(Params[1].Value);
```

it is returning ok, a value of `0`, since execution of stored procedure is being executed correctly and no `@@ROWCOUNT=0` condition is being satisfied within the stored procedure.

However if I launch stored procedure from SQL Server against the same database:

```sql
DECLARE @OutputCode char(50)    
DECLARE @Error int 
DECLARE @SearchCode char(10) = '12003'

EXEC [dbo].[MySP] @SearchCode, @Error OUTPUT,  @OutputCode OUTPUT
select @Error, @OutputCode
```

Then I get the correct value for `@OutputCode` that is a string different from `"0"`.

I have ensured that first query within store procedure:

```sql
SELECT @OutputCode=SomeField FROM SearchTable WHERE FieldToSearch=@SearchCode
```

is being executed correctly and return one row and one column, so `@OutputCode` is assigned a value correctly.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: You are not adding a type to commandParameters.  Your procedure expects the following types :     DECLARE Flag1 bit;
    DECLARE IDate date;
    DECLARE FDate date;
    DECLARE TypeM tinyin;

Comment: @jdweng you mean to specify a type for the parameters  from C# before calling the stored procedure?

Comment: @jdweng Those are variables internal to the stored proc, they don't need to be declared/defined in the C# at all. You probably meant the in params `@SearchCode` , `@Error` and `@OutputCode`, yeah?

Comment: Actually there are two object not declared : SomeCondition and SomeCondition2

Comment: If it returns "0" - then it's being read by C#, because default value you assigned to that parameter was "' (empty string ) and not "0". If the error was read or not we have no idea, because it was 0 initially, so the fact it is still 0 after execution doesn't tell us it was read correctly.

Comment: Are you reading the parameter before you execute this line of code? `cmd.Parameters.Clear();`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not being specifying the size of the output parameter. Since I was only passing the value as an empty string, SQL Server by default was taking a size of 1 character instead of 50. Consequently, from C# I was receiving the first character, that in this case, was "0".

Specifying the size for the output parameter solves the problem:

```
Params[2] = new SqlParameter();
Params[2].SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
Params[2].ParameterName = "@OutputCode";
Params[2].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
Params[2].Size = 50;  // should be >=50
Params[2].Value = string.Empty;
```

**Notes**:
In case of output parameter is less than 50 characters we receive blank spaces at the end so we need to remove spaces at the end using Trim function from C#.